# "No such file or directory" - but it does exist - Windows 7

Tags: command-line, windows-7, rm

I am updating some old Windows 7 PCs (they will be upgraded to Windows 10 by the end of the year) via batch script (I only have access via SSH) and am running into a problem I have not had before - in fact, commands like this one have worked fine before, but suddenly not.  This one stymies me.

I am in this directory (so I know it exists):

```
C:\HALS 2000\win7>ls -l
total 2908
-rwx------+ 1 Administrators None  880877 Jan 21 08:17 upgrade.8.54.zip
-rwx------+ 1 Administrators None  934641 Jan 21 08:17 upgrade.8.60.zip
-rwx------+ 1 Administrators None 1153914 Jan 16 12:27 upgrade.8.61.zip
```

And I use this command:

```
if exist c:\"HALS 2000"\win7\*.* rm c:\"HALS 2000"\win7\*.*
```

but I get

```
rm: cannot remove 'c:\\HALS 2000\\win7\\*.*': No such file or directory
```

WTF?  I've used this command many batch updates before.

So I tested this command while remotely logged into one of the PCs:

```
if exist \"HALS 2000"\win7\*.* rm \"HALS 2000"\win7\*.*
```

And I get:

```
rm: cannot remove '\\HALS 2000win7*.*': No such file or directory
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: FYI - this command finally worked - `if exist \"HALS 2000"\win7\*.* del \"HALS 2000"\win7\*.* /Q` - but I'd like to know why the rm commands are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because wildcarded filenames are handled differently on Unix and Windows.

In Unix, wildcarded arguments (arguments containing `*` and `?`) are expanded by the shell (the command-line handler) and the results of the expansion are substituted for the wildcard in the list of arguments that are passed to the program.  If you had run that `rm` command on a Unix system then the arguments that `rm` received would have been the list of names `upgrade.8.54.zip`, 
`upgrade.8.60.zip` and `upgrade.8.61.zip`.  `rm` then takes each argument in turn and tries to delete it.

In Windows, wildcarded arguments are not expanded by the command-line handler.  The wildcard is passed unmodified as an argument into the program, and it's up to the program itself to find the filenames that match the wildcard.

Because `rm` is originally a Unix program, it is written to expect that the shell will take care of wildcards.  `rm` is not written to perform wildcard expansion internally.  When it is invoked on Windows as `rm c:\HALS 2000\win7\*.*` and is passed the unexpanded argument `c:\HALS 2000\win7\*.*` it tries to delete a file whose name is exactly, literally, `c:\HALS 2000\win7\*.*`.  No such file exists, so the delete attempt fails and `rm` reports an error.

`del` is a Windows command, so it was written with the expectation that it might be asked to handle the expansion of wildcard arguments.  When it is given the argument `c:\HALS 2000\win7\*.*` it finds the files whose names match that wildcard and deletes them.